# Is the core topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ a group topology?

Tags: general-topology

The core topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the final topology induced by the inclusions $i_{v,w} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$, $t \mapsto v + t w$ of lines (affine one-dimensional subspaces), where $\mathbb{R}$ carries the Euclidean topology and $v, w \in \mathbb{R}^2$. In other words, a set is open if its intersection with every line is an open subset of the line with its (one-dimensional) Euclidean topology. These open sets are also known as algebraically open. Thus, a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is algebraically open if and only if for every point $v \in A$ and every direction $w \in \mathbb{R}^2$ there is $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $A$ contains with $v$ also the whole open line segment $v + (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) w$. Note that the choice of $\varepsilon$ depends on the direction $w$.

The core topology is strictly finer than the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$, but a convex algebraically open set is also open w.r.t. the Euclidean topology. Thus, an algebraically open set that is not Euclidean open must be necessarily non-convex. As an example, the set $A := (\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus S^1) \cup \{ (1,0) \}$ is algebraically open but not Euclidean open: if $L \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is a line then $A \cap L = L \setminus S$ where $|S| \leq 2$, thus $A \cap L$ is an Euclidean open subset of $L$. But there is no two-dimensional (Euclidean) open ball around $(1,0)$ completely contained in $A$.

The core topology is clearly translation-invariant, i.e. the vector addition $+ : \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, $(x,y) \mapsto x + y$ is continuous separately in each of its components. Is vector addition moreover continuous (where the domain carries the product topology)? In other words, is the core topology a group topology? I think, for this purpose it would be nice to have an explicit description of some nice base for the core topology. (I was not able to create a contradiction for the set $A$ above.)

Comment: This is more commonly called the "radial plane"; it's quite interesting: separable, but not Lindelöf, sequential but not first countable. Not locally compact, or normal.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I met the name "core topology" when defining this topology on an arbitrary vector space $X$. Thank you for giving me the name of this topology for $X = \mathbb{R}^2$. [S. P. Franklin,  Solution to Monthly Problem #5468, American Mathematical Monthly 75 (1968), p. 208] shows that this topology is not even regular (http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2315929.pdf). It follows in particular, that the radial topology is not a group topology, since group topologies carry a compatible uniform structure and are thus completely regular.

Comment: I could not read Franklin's answer. (No online access) could you sketch the reason for non- regularity? Non-normal follows from Jones' Lemma I think.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Sure. Since the Euclidean topology on the plane is second-countable one can choose a countable dense subset $D$ such that no three points are collinear. Then $D$ is radially closed. Let $U$ be a radial nbhd. of $\alpha \in D$. Then there is a closed horizontal line segment $L$ through $\alpha$ in $U$. Let $F_n$ be the set of points of $L$ which are the center of a vertical segment with length $\geq 1/n$ which is contained in $U$. Then $L = \bigcup F_n$ and by Baire category, there is some $n$ such that the closure of $F_n$ in $L$ contains an interval.

Comment: It follows that the radial closure of $U$ has a non-empty Euclidean interior and hence contains a point of $D$. Thus, the radial topology is not regular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be a vector space, $\tau$ a topology on $X$ and consider the following compatibility properties of $\tau$ with the vector space structure of $X$:

(i) addition is continuous

(i') addition is continuous separately in its components (i.e. translations are homeomorphisms)

(ii) scalar multiplication is continuous

(ii') scalar multiplication is continuous separately in its components.

The core topology $\tau_c$ on $X$ is known to be the finest topology satisfying (i') and (ii'). The following shows that $\tau_c$ does neither satisfy (i) nor (ii) whenver $\dim(X) \geq 2$.

As Henno Brandsma pointed out in his comment, the core topology $\tau_c$ on $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ is also known as the "radial plane" topology, see e.g. [Willard, "General Topology"]. [S. P. Franklin, Solution to Monthly Problem #5468, American Mathematical Monthly 75 (1968), p. 208] shows that this topology is *not regular*. Since a group topology is completely regular (it carries a compatible uniform structure induced by the group structure) it follows that $\tau_c$ does not satisfy (i).

Moreover, $\tau_c$ does not satisfy (ii) since the Euclidean topology (on a finite-dimensional space) is known to be the finest topology with (i') and (ii). (The finest topology on a generic vector space having (i') and (ii) coincides with the the finite topology (= the finest topology that induces the Euclidean topology on every finite-dimensional subspace).)

**Addendum**: The fact that $\tau_c$ is not regular was also already shown by [Klee, "Some finite-dimensional affine topological spaces" (1955)].